# Regulator/heatsink heating up even though load is only 50% of regulator Imax

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, heatsink

aI have made a small +/- 24VDC liner supply for the use of powering an audio preamp PCBA. LM317 for plus/ LM337 for the neg (both TO-220), 10uf output capacitance added. Even though this circuit doesn't draw more than about 700mA (inly 50% of what these regulators are spec'd to), my heatsinks are heating up pretty seriously after about a half hour. The output of the regulator looks good, but i am trying to manage my heat dissipation issue. The heatsink's I've chosen are larger than what you might expect  (google "SK 104 63,5 STS" you'll see the ficsher electronik heatsink I've selected) transformer secondary voltage is 28vac converted after the bridge to 28 DC via a 4700uf electrolytic. I have only two questions:

1. Both of my heatsinks are mounted to perf board, and not touching one another, not touching any other component nor ground. If i have not efficiently isolated the output to the heatsink and due to the 317/architecture the base plate is allowing the voltage to flow to the heatsink itself, even though it's really not going anywhere - could the energy just being in the heatsink cause the regulator to work harder, thus generating that heat?
2. If I add two to-220 package Darlington's to increase the output load capabilities of both regulators, i understand i would have to heat sink them as well, but will that decrease the overall heat dissipation already being generated without them (i suspect not, i suspect it will just radiate out of the heatisnks for the darlingtons)?

Comment: You need to analyze the *power* dissipated, not the *current*. Please add a schematic.

Comment: What thermal resistance is each heatsink, and what power dissipation in each regulator? NOTE 28V AC after a bridge and a reservoir cap is NOT 28VDC. It's more like 39V DC. 15V 0.7A call it 10W, 8K/W heatsink, 80C temperature rise is what you expect.

Comment: What is the actual voltage at the input of the regulator - a 28V transformer will normally give out much more than 28V DC after rectification. The fact that 700mA is much less than the 1.5A capability is irrelevant. It is the power dissipation that is important.

Comment: to Brian Drummond - thank you for responding so quickly and for forgiving my silly misspelling in the title. The 317 is spec'd at 15 W power dissipation max and the heatsink is seced at 8 °C/W thermal resistance

Comment: You're dissipating a lot of heat through a fairly high thermal resistance heatsink, so it gets hot. Your options are a bigger heatsink or dissipating less heat.

Comment: Thank you....and you told me what i suspected was the solution...i was just hoping for another option (bigger heatsink). With COVID, i dont have access to a good bench saw, so if a purchased a beam-type heatsink i'll have to cross my fingers and pull out a hacksaw praying it can cut it cleanly

Comment: Kevin White: I measured the secondary at 31 volts VAC each side of the centerr tap without a load, it dropped to 28 and change once the bridge, filter cap and regulator was added.

Comment: Hacksaw, kerosene lubricant, new blade, you'll be done in minutes.

Answer (score 6):

The key things to figure out are:

- Regulator current
- Voltage drop

The first you've stated as 700mA.

The second we'll figure out. 24V AC will regulate to 24V/0.707 = 34V DC. With 24V output, we have a drop of as much as 10V (34V in - 24V out.)

10V at 700mA will dissipate... 7W in your part, worst-case. That's kind of a lot for the LM317 / 337 in TO-220.

Comment: Just to add: 28V is the rms value of the transformer output. Under no load, the smoothing capacitor will charge up to the peak value, which is 1.4142 (i.e. root 2) times greater, over 39 V. Under a load of 700mA that will reduce, but the amount depends on the transformer specification and its input impedance. You could easily be dropping around 12-14V across those regulators.